# ubuntu - How to run react-native examples?

Tags: react-native

I followed by Readme for Examples on https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/0.35-stable but when i `./packager/packager.sh` for fix error in android emulator `could not connect to development server` I have

```
@asus ➜  react-native-0.35-stable  ./packager/packager.sh

ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/home/andrey/vimfiles/ackrc'
```

If run `npm start` then have

```
@asus ➜  TicTacToe  npm start      
> react-native@0.35.0 start /home/andrey/react-native-0.35-stable       
> /usr/bin/env bash -c './packager/packager.sh "$@" || true' --  


ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/home/andrey/vimfiles/ackrc'
```

Comment: Try reinstalling react native globally `npm uninstall react-native-cli -g` then `npm install -g react-native-cli`

Comment: @LuisEstevez the same